# how to refresh content of JTree in java?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree which shows content of specific directory. When a download some file with ftp to this directory i want to let my JTree know about it and refresh his contents.
How can i refresh JTree after some file added or removed from directory which is root for JTree?

```
btnRefreshContents.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tree.getModel().
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Java 7, you can use the new [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) ([`FileSystem.newWatchService()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#newWatchService%28%29)) to detect changes to the filesystem.  Here's an [article on it](http://e-blog-java.blogspot.com.au/2011/03/how-to-watch-file-system-for-changes-in.html).

As to updating the JTree component, take a look at this [Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913855/how-can-i-refresh-a-jtree-after-adding-some-nodes-to-the-underlying-model).

Comment: You are right, but i have no other chooses.I have to use Java 1.5.
Is it good idea to reload a JTree with the same directory again after adding files to it?

Answer (score 0):

You could add directory listener to the underlying tree model. There are many solutions for that. As already stated [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382772/1048330), `WatchService` in Java 7 can be useful. But since you are not yet at Java 7 you can try other approaches:

[JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) - java library that allows java application to listen to file system events. Here is a [sample](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/sample.html) (make sure you add dll/so dependency to your path.)

[VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) from Apache Commons. Commons VFS provides a single API for accessing various different file systems. [DefaultFileMonitor](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/impl/DefaultFileMonitor.html) is a good example.