# I need to refresh a JTreeModel having only a TreeNode

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I need to notify a node's children changed, and for what I've seen from various sources (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913855/how-can-i-refresh-a-jtree-after-adding-some-nodes-to-the-underlying-model)) I need to act on the JTreeModel.
The problem is I don't have either the JTree object nor the JTreeModel object. All I have are the tree's nodes.

Is there a way?

Comment: Short answer - no, and it's very, very annoying.  A `TreeNode` is sub model of `TreeModel` and it should be able to generate events which the model listens to, but it's not implemented that way, and it's very annoying

Comment: I ended up writing my JTreeModel into the root TreeNode. So annoying.

Comment: I've, in the past, create a event listener into `TreeNode` which generates events in such away that the `TreeModel` listens to the root node and each parent node listens to it's children, the events are then cascaded back up the call chain